# What are the benefits of std::distance over subtracting iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, stdvector

I'm iterating over a vector and need the index the iterator is currently pointing at. What are the pros and cons of the following methods?

- `it - vec.begin()`
- `std::distance(vec.begin(), it)`

Answer (score 704, accepted):

I would prefer `it - vec.begin()` precisely for the opposite reason given by Naveen: so it *wouldn't* compile if you change the vector into a list. If you do this during every iteration, you could easily end up turning an O(n) algorithm into an O(n^2) algorithm.

Another option, if you don't jump around in the container during iteration, would be to keep the index as a second loop counter.

Note: `it` is a common name for a container iterator,`std::container_type::iterator it;`.

Comment: Agreed.  I'd say that the minus sign is best, but it would be better to keep a second loop counter than to use std::distance, precisely because this function could be slow.

Comment: @Steinfeld its an iterator. `std::container_type::iterator it;`

Comment: Adding a second loop counter is such an obvious solution that I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it.

Comment: @UncleBeans Why we cannot use the - operator for List?

Comment: @Swapnil because `std::list` does not offer direct access to elements by their position, so if you cannot do `list[5]`, you shouldn't be able to do `list.begin() + 5`.

Comment: The type would be `long`:

`long n = it - vec.begin();`

Answer (score 171):

I would prefer `std::distance(vec.begin(), it)` as it will allow me to change the container without any code changes. For example, if you decide to use `std::list` instead of `std::vector` which doesn't provide a random access iterator your code will still compile. Since std::distance picks up the optimal method depending on iterator traits you'll not have any performance degradation either.

Comment: When you're using a container without random access iterators, it's best *not to* compute such distances because it's inefficient

Comment: @Eli: I agree with that, but in a very special case if it is really required, then still that code will work.

Comment: I think the code should be changed anyway if the container changes - having a std::list variable named `vec` is bad news. If the code were re-written to be generic, taking the container type as a template parameter, that's when we can (and should) talk about handling non-random-access iterators ;-)

Comment: And specialisation for certain containers.

Comment: @SteveJessop : Having a vector named `vec` is pretty bad news, too.

Comment: @EliBendersky It's better to have working code first, then optimize. Inducing a compilation failure because the code *may* be slow is plainly wrong.

Answer (score 88):

As UncleBens and Naveen have shown, there are good reasons for both. Which one is "better" depends on what behavior you want: Do you want to guarantee constant-time behavior, or do you want it to fall back to linear time when necessary?

`it - vec.begin()` takes constant time, but the `operator -` is only defined on random access iterators, so the code won't compile at all with list iterators, for example.

`std::distance(vec.begin(), it)` works for all iterator types, but will only be a constant-time operation if used on random access iterators.

Neither one is "better". Use the one that does what you need.

Comment: I've fallen foul of this in the past. Using std::distance on two std::map iterators and expecting it to be O(N).

Comment: @ScaryAardvark: Don't you mean expecting it to be O(1)?

Answer (score 14):

I like this one: `it - vec.begin()`, because to me it clearly says "distance from beginning". With iterators we're used to thinking in terms of arithmetic, so the `-` sign is the clearest indicator here.

Comment: It's more clear to use subtraction to find the distance than to use, quite literally, the word `distance` ?

Comment: @Travis, to me it is. It's a matter of taste and custom. We say `it++` and not something like `std::increment(it)`, don't we? Wouldn't that also count as less clear?

Comment: The `++` operator is defined as part of the STL sequences as how we increment the iterator.  `std::distance` calculates the number of elements between the first and last element.  The fact that the `-` operator works is merely a coincidence.

Comment: @MSalters: and yet, we use ++ :-)

Answer (score 11):

If you are already restricted/hardcoded your algorithm to using a `std::vector::iterator` and `std::vector::iterator` only, it doesn't really matter which method you will end up using. Your algorithm is already concretized beyond the point where choosing one of the other can make any difference. They both do exactly the same thing. It is just a matter of personal preference. I would personally use explicit subtraction.

If, on the other hand, you want to retain a higher degree of generality in your algorithm, namely, to allow the possibility that some day in the future it might be applied to some other iterator type, then the best method depends on your intent. It depends on how restrictive you want to be with regard to the iterator type that can be used here.

- If you use the explicit subtraction, your algorithm will be restricted to a rather narrow class of iterators: random-access iterators. (This is what you get now from `std::vector`)
- If you use `distance`, your algorithm will support a much wider class of iterators: input iterators.

Of course, calculating `distance` for non-random-access iterators is in general case an inefficient operation (while, again, for random-access ones it is as efficient as subtraction). It is up to you to decide whether your algorithm *makes sense* for non-random-access iterators, efficiency-wise. It the resultant loss in efficiency is devastating to the point of making your algorithm completely useless, then you should better stick to subtraction, thus prohibiting the inefficient uses and forcing the user to seek alternative solutions for other iterator types. If the efficiency with non-random-access iterators is still in usable range, then you should use `distance` and document the fact that the algorithm works better with random-access iterators.

Answer (score 5):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/, since `vec.begin()` is a *random access* iterator, the distance method uses the `-` operator.

So the answer is, from a performance point of view, it is the same, but maybe using `distance()` is easier to understand if anybody would have to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the `-` variant for `std::vector` only - it's pretty clear what is meant, and the simplicity of the operation (which isn't more than a pointer subtraction) is expressed by the syntax (`distance`, on the other side, sounds like pythagoras on the first reading, doesn't it?). As UncleBen points out, `-` also acts as a static assertion in case `vector` is accidentially changed to `list`.

Also I think it is much more common - have no numbers to prove it, though. Master argument: `it - vec.begin()` is shorter in source code - less typing work, less space consumed. As it's clear that the right answer to your question boils down to be a matter of taste, this can *also* be a valid argument.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered this: https://greek0.net/boost-range/boost-adaptors-indexed.html

```cpp
    for (const auto & element : str | boost::adaptors::indexed(0)) {
        std::cout << element.index()
                  << " : "
                  << element.value()
                  << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside int float string etc., you can put extra data to .second when using diff. types like:

```
std::map<unsigned long long int, glm::ivec2> voxels_corners;
std::map<unsigned long long int, glm::ivec2>::iterator it_corners;
```

or

```
struct voxel_map {
    int x,i;
};

std::map<unsigned long long int, voxel_map> voxels_corners;
std::map<unsigned long long int, voxel_map>::iterator it_corners;
```

when

```
long long unsigned int index_first=some_key; // llu in this case...
int i=0;
voxels_corners.insert(std::make_pair(index_first,glm::ivec2(1,i++)));
```

or

```
long long unsigned int index_first=some_key;
int index_counter=0;
voxel_map one;
one.x=1;
one.i=index_counter++;

voxels_corners.insert(std::make_pair(index_first,one));
```

with right type || structure you can put anything in the .second including a index number that is incremented when doing an insert.

instead of

```
it_corners - _corners.begin()
```

or

```
std::distance(it_corners.begin(), it_corners)
```

after

```
it_corners = voxels_corners.find(index_first+bdif_x+x_z);
```

the index is simply:

```
int vertice_index = it_corners->second.y;
```

when using the glm::ivec2 type

or

```
int vertice_index = it_corners->second.i;
```

in case of the structure data type

Comment: When using large amounts of data the gained speed without the 

    it - vec.begin()

or

    std::distance(vec.begin(), it)

using the index inserted with the make_pair is more than 100 times...

makes you think, "witch one is better?" 

using an index in the .second field along with the other data you want to store with another data type / structure.