# C++ search vector for MAX, and get same position form a second vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am using C++ and i have 2 vectors that a related to each other:

```
vector<double> val = {.3,.5,.2,.4};
vector<string> str = {'a','b','c','d'};
```

I would like to search val for the max, and then return the string from str in the same position:

```
vector<double>::const_iterator it;
it = max_element(val.begin(), val.end());
```

So, how can i use `it` inside `str` to get the letter?

```
string lettter;
letter = str.at(it-> ????? );
```

Thank!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out how far `it` is from the beginning of `val` and then use that to index `str`:

```
str[std::distance(std::begin(val), it)]
```

By using `std::distance`, this will still work if you change the type of `val` to a container whose iterator does not provide random access. However, when using it on a random access iterator, you will still get constant time complexity. Using `std::begin` allows you to change `val` to an C-style array if you ever wanted to.

It's worth mentioning that you should be initialising `str` with:

```
vector<string> str = {"a","b","c","d"};
```

`std::string` has no constructor that takes a `char`.

Comment: i see an error that says "No instance of function template std::distance matches the argument list" ------ I tried     `str[std::distance(std::begin(val), *it)]` same thing

Comment: @Special--k I think your problem is that `it` is a `const_iterator` while `std::begin` gives an `iterator`. Unfortunately, there is no `std::cbegin` (an oversight in the standard). You can either make `it` an `iterator` or implement `cbegin` yourself. Or you could just use `val.cbegin()` instead of `std::begin(val)`.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
letter = str.at(it - val.begin());
```

?

[(Rationale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator/2153160#2153160)

Comment: I think `std::distance` is slightly better because it will work with lists and other containers. The rationale you link doesn't really apply here because `max_element` is already O(n) so adding another possibly O(n) operation won't matter that much.

Comment: Lots of good answers, i ended up going with the distance() answer. So it seemed fair to give that answer the nod. Wish i could accept 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

Get the index of the element like so:

```
auto index = std::distance(val.begin(), it);
```

Then index into your string array:

```
auto letter = str[index];
```

---

Note that if these values are correlated, you should probably forcibly keep them together:

```
typedef std::pair<double, string> valstr_pair;
std::vector<valstr_pair> valstr;

auto it = std::max_element(valstr.begin(), valstr.end(),
    [](const valstr_pair& first, const valstr_pair& second)
    {
        return first.first < second.first; // compare values
    });

it->first;  // max value
it->second; // string of max value
```

Comment: Its a good idea, but i would then just use a map.  The problem is that my vectors are filled up at different times in my application. That is not evident in my simple example above. So, i cannot keep the values together because at the time the strings (Files names) are inserted into their vector, the doubles (a score function) has no been run.  I guess i could insert the files names with all 0's and then just update them once the score is calculated.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the distance between the iterator returned by `max_element()` and the beginning of the vector:

`std::distance(val.begin(), it)`.

You can then use it as an index into `str`.