# How to get index of bidirectional iterator with std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

[What is the most effective way to get the index of an iterator of an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator) explains how to do it for `std::vector` or `std::list` but what about `std::map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this would be to use the `std::distance` function:

```
auto index = std::distance(myMap.begin(), myMapItr);
```

However, this runs in O(n) time, which is inefficient for large maps.

If you need to determine the index of an iterator into a map or other ordered collection, you may want to search for a library containing an [order statistic tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), which is a modified binary search tree that supports efficient (O(1) or O(log n)) time lookup of the index of a particular value in the tree.

Alternatively, if you are manually iterating over the tree, you can just keep a counter lying around alongside the iterator that you increment every time you traverse from one element to the next.  This gives O(1)-time lookup of the index of the iterator, but is not fully general.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is why I love this website.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
int IndexOf(Type *t)
{
    Type** data = vector.data();

    int index = 0;

    while(*data++ != t)
    {
        index ++;
    }

    return index ;
}
```

Comment: -1 because this gets the index of a _value_ in a vector, not the equivalent index of an iterator (a position) in a map.