# index of property tree const iterator

Tags: c++, boost, indexing, iterator

I am using boost 1.55.0 and want to iterate through a property tree and I need the index of the iterator.

I used the answer from this question: [What is the most effective way to get the index of an iterator of an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator)

The for loop and the try to obtain the index look like:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree sensors;
for(boost::property_tree::ptree::const_iterator it = sensors.begin(); it != sensors.end(); ++it)
{           
    auto idx = it - sensors.begin();
}
```

But I get this compiler error:

```
/Boost1p55p0/build/include/boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp:224:7: error: 
  static_assert failed "(is_convertible<Tr1, Tr2>::value)"
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((is_convertible<Tr1, Tr2>::value));
  ^                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
........
in instantiation of function template specialization
  'boost::operator-<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>,
  std::basic_string<char>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> > >::const_iterator,
  std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>,
  boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>,
  std::less<std::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, const
  std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>,
  boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>,
  std::less<std::basic_string<char> > > > &, long,
  boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>,
  std::less<std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator, std::pair<const
  std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>,
  std::basic_string<char>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> > > >,
  boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>,
  boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>,
  std::less<std::basic_string<char> > > > &, long>' requested here
            auto idxIt = it - sensors.begin();
```

What is wrong, and how can I obtain the index as uint?

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS with clang 3.4.

Comment: Iterators don't necessarily support arbitrary moves. "Index" is not necessarily available (and sensible), especially for complex structures like trees or hashes.

Comment: so there is no other way, to obtain the index than to count how often the iterator got increased? For example have another variable counting the cycles of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may check if [std::distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/) is suitable for your needs. But remember that counting distance for iterators which don't support random access may lead to O(N) operations (N `++`-es)