# Most efficient way to get the index of an iterator for a map? C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator?lq=1) thread, I'm trying to get the integer index from an iterator but for a map instead of an vector. Atm its causing a large bottle neck in my code and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to get the index other that what I'm doing currently...

```
auto itTail = nodesMap.find(tail);
tailNodePos = distance(nodesMap.begin(), itTail);
```

Comment: map iterators are invalidated at insertions AFAIK, are the element stable or you're planning on inserting/deleting a lot?

Comment: What is the point of `tailNodePos`? You cannot really use it to insert elements. Just save `tail` and use it to find the position again or save the iterator `itTail`. Keep in mind the invalidation on every insert / erase.

Comment: The elements are stable... I'm using the map to build an adjacency list represented by a vector of vectors, where the position in the first vector corresponds to the position of a corresponding element in the map

Comment: If the map is stable, what is the point of using the map? Sorting + binary search is a better option if no inserts/deletes are performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is impossible to get the index for an arbitrary iterator for a `map` faster than `O(container size)`(according to `map` specification in C++ standard). If it is very important to do it much faster, I would try using custom balanced binary search tree(because it is possible to get an index for a node in a tree in `O(log(container size))` if each node in a tree maintains sub tree size).
And if there are no inserts and deletes performed, it is easy to use sorted `vector` and `lower_bound` instead of `map` and `find`(this approach allows to get the index in `O(1)` because `vector` iterator is a random access iterator).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a container with fast indexing (nth element, and index-of-element) and fast sort-ordered insert/delete, you will have to write your own, or find one outside of `std`.

It is not that tricky a design -- a b-tree or rb-tree where each node also keeps count of how many nodes are under it has only a modest overhead over a 'naked' one.  Writing the rest of the interface to match `std::map` is a slog, as is writing raw tree manipulation code.

I tried to find one in `boost` a few years ago and failed.  Maybe something with multi-index container: but there, the sequence is order of insertion, not order-in-map component.