# how to find the max element between the m-th and the n-th element of a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

It seems that the function max_element for vector would work for this purpose but I am not sure how to use it.

```
ForwardIterator max_element (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last);
```

What is the type of ForwardIterator? How do I specify that it searches starting from the m-th element? And how do I find the index of the max element? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
std::max_element(vec.begin() + m, vec.begin() + n);
```

assuming `m < n` and `n <= vec.size()`, where `vec` is a `std::vector` object.

This will return an iterator to the max-value element in the specified range, to get the corresponding index use `it - vec.begin()` where `it` is the max-element iterator.

Comment: Then how do I know which element is the max element?

Comment: `std::max_element` returns the iterator to the max element in the range.

Comment: But I need to know the position of this element, for example, i want to know if it is the first, second, or third element. I want to know the integer which specifies the position.

Comment: @Resorter [index from iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/effective-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator), the answer was a quick google search away.

Comment: Just use `it - vec.begin()` to get the index, where `it` is the max-element iterator

Comment: Do you mean std::max_element(vec.begin() + m-1, vec.begin() + n-1); ? and it-vec.begin()+1  ?

Comment: @Resorter: `std::vector` is 0-indexed. `m` and `n` need to be 0-based values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Resorter it would be good to edit your Question to say that you want to know the index of the element

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury If the container changes, a more generic approach to get the position is `std::distance(vec.begin(), it);`

Answer (score 2):

This signature is telling you that `std::max_element` is a template that accepts arguments of any type so long as it meets the forward iterator requirements, and it returns the same type. You would simply pass in the iterators and it would return an iterator to the maximum element found in the range. You can dereference that to get the value itself. Hence

```
const auto max_iterator = std::max_element(v.begin() + m, v.begin() + n);
const auto max_value = *i;
```

Care must be taken to avoid the case where `m` is greater than or equal to `n`.