# Using the find algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

I have an assignment that I am working on that has the function outline provided. I am supposed to return the position of the found item if it is found or -1 if not.
Here is that outline code:

```
int linearSearch( const vector<int>& inputVec, int x)  {
```

and I have to fill in the function using the `find` algorithm. My understanding is that `find` returns an iterator. I'm just not sure how to take that and return an integer that is the position or a -1.
Right now I am trying this on the inside.

```
auto it = find(inputVec.begin(), inputVec.end(), x);
```

and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I doubt you're supposed to it this way. A direct linear search would be a lot faster most likely. Either way, if you absolutely want to it using `std::find`, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator-of-an-stdvector).

Comment: You can check the range between the `it` and `inputVec.begin()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do manual looping like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<inputVec.size();i++) {
    if(inputVec[i]==x) return i;
}
return -1;
```

Or if you want to use find() function:

```
auto it = find(inputVec.begin(), inputVec.end(), x);
if(it==inputVec.end()) return -1;
return it - inputVec.begin();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be using the `find` algorithm as required by the assignment.

Comment: if(it==inputVec.end()) return -1; else return it - inputVec.begin();

Comment: That looks better...now check it and then add it to your answer.

Comment: the assignment ask to implement linearSearch(), I am not sure why he wrap the find() function.

Comment: The assignment is: _Here is that outline code:
`int linearSearch( const vector<int>& inputVec, int x)  {`
and I have to fill in the function using the `find` algorithm._  So, the function he has to write is called `linearSearch()` and he is supposed to use `find` inside the function.  It doesn't seem to be particularly difficult to understand.

Comment: I used the second version to incorporate the find function. But it doesn't seem to like the if statement that comes after it. I get the error message: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::pair<__gnu_cxx<const int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> > >' and 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}' )