# Finding minimum element of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to find the minimum element of a vector in C++. I wish to return both the value of the lowest element and the position of the index within the vector. Here is what I have tried,

```
    auto minIt = std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    auto minElement = *minIt;
       std::cout << "\nMinIT " << &minIt << " while minElement is " << minElement << "\n";
```

This returns the following,

```
MinIT 8152610 while minElement is 8152610
```

How do I obtain the index i of vec(i) where this value is?

Comment: `minIt - vec.begin()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The return of `std::min_element` is an *iterator*, which you are obfuscating by your use of `auto`.

You can get the position of it in the vector using

`std::distance(vec.begin(), std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()));`

which is more "C++ Standard Library"-esque than the less generic

`std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()) - vec.begin();`

although there are differences in opinion on the merits of either way. See [What is the most effective way to get the index of an iterator of an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator-of-an-stdvector)

Further references: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant answer! Could you expand it to deal with two dimensional vectors too? I will update my question via an edit!

Comment: It's best to ask a new question from scratch. Methinks the answer will be very different.