# Python's enumerate in c++

Tags: c++, enumerator

In Python , instead of

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']

for i in range(len(colors)):
    print i, '--->', colors[i]
```

One can write

```
for i, color in enumerate(colors):
    print i, '--->', color
```

Is there a similar thing in c++?

Comment: I don't think so. If you iterate over a `std::vector`, it just gives you the elements, not the indexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most effective way to get the index of an iterator of an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator-of-an-stdvector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually implement something similar in c++17.

Here is a sketch(c++-ish pseudocode), I use values everywhere and they should be replaced by appropriate references/forwarding, also you should fix how you get types (use iterator_traits), may be support unknown size, may be implement proper iterator interface etc

```
template <typename T>
struct EnumeratedIterator {
    size_t index;
    T iterator;
    void operator++() {
        ++iterator;
    }
    std::pair<size_t, T>() {
        return {index, *iterator};
    }
    bool operator !=(EnumeratedIterator o) {
        return iterator != o.iterator;
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct Enumerated {
    T collection;
    EnumeratedIterator<typename T::iterator> begin() {
        return {0, collection.begin()};
    }
    EnumeratedIterator<typename T::iterator> end() {
        return {collection.size(), collection.end()};
    }
}

auto enumerate(T col) {
    return Enumerated<T>(col);
}
```

and then use it like

```
for (auto [index, color] : enumerate(vector<int>{5, 7, 10})) {
    assert(index < color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boost provides an adaptor which allows to do something similiar:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html

The following code is taken from the link above

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indexed.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::assign;
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    std::vector<int> input;
    input += 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90;

    for (const auto& element : input | indexed(0))
    {
        std::cout << "Element = " << element.value()
                  << " Index = " << element.index()
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#operator+=

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can emulate it like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto color : { "red", "green", "blue", "yellow" })
    std::cout << i++ << "--->" << color << std::endl;
```

Comment: and now run this function two times and you'll get 4,5,6,7 instead of indexes

Comment: @RiaD this is not a function

Comment: @KillzoneKid No, but this code must be put inside a function somewhere, and when it does, the `static` will cause issues on repeated invocations of the function. Just remove the `static` keyword and move your `i` initialisation to before the loop.