# Alternative to string::npos

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In a scenario where a custom `find()` method of a custom class returns index position of an element in a custom data structure, is there something more elegant than returning `string::npos`?

The return type of the `find()` method is `size_t`.  So I need it to be of type size_t.

`string::npos` is `-1`, which is the maximum value of `unsigned long long`. While this works great, my issue with it is the naming: `string`.  I'd prefer not to have any association to `string`.  Is there anything built in more generally named for such a common and general scenario and compatible with `size_t`?

Comment: Why are you asking? Where are you using this? What do you mean by "associtation to string"?

Comment: Vectors and sets return `vec.end()` and `set.end()`, respectively, when `find()` fails...

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. You could use `std::find`, but if you're searching `string` you might as well use `string` methods.

Comment: I'm not talking about vector or string. I have a custom class with a custom data structure.  I just want to return index position of an element. In case not found I need to return something.  While string::npos works fine...I don't like that it is packaged in the string class...which has nothing to do with my class.

Comment: Then define a `yourclass::npos`. (which is likely to equal to `(size_t)-1` as well)

Comment: You could always return an `optional`.

Comment: I would avoid indexes and use iterators if at all possible.

Comment: Why is that Galik?

Comment: @Galik "indices"?

Comment: @user202729 both versions are good :)

Comment: @code Iterators are generally safer. Most algorithms expect iterators. And the iterator equivalent of `npos` is `std::end(v)` which is *one past the end* and that just happens to work out better when using it in further processes. The problem with `npos` is you often have to convert it to something useful before you can use it in a subsequent algorithm (like size()).

Comment: If you do use iterators, the two competing method for returning the current index based on an iterator would be [How to get index from iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator-of-an-stdvector) which would apply equally to *string* using `std::string::iterator`.

Comment: Great points everyone.  I see what you mean Galik.

Comment: If you want something "more elegant", you may have to explain the ways in which you think _npos_ is inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom class wants to return a size_t from it's find function, then just define your own size_t constant for consumers to reference as being "not found".  For example (pseudo-code, not verified to compile):

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        static const size_t npos = static_cast<size_t>(-1);

        size_t find(/*thing to find here*/) const
        {
            // logic to search for element

            // element not found
            return(npos);
        }
};
```

and then consumer can use it similarly to std::string:

```
Foo foo;
size_t pos = foo.find(/*thing to find here*/);
if(pos != Foo::npos)
{
    // Element found
}
```

Comment: Why did u static_cast? static_cast<size_t>(-1);

Comment: @code Not sure which aspect you're asking about, but...IIRC some compilers will warn if trying to assign a negative number to an unsigned type, especially at the higher (more critical/pedantic) warning levels.  And 'static_cast' definitely over C-style cast for its benefits.