# How to get int position of vector loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector

How to get int position of this loop? Thank you.

```
auto a = vect.begin();
auto b = vect2.begin();
auto c = vect3.begin();
for (; a != vect.end() && b != vect2.end() && c != vect3.end(); a++, b++, c++) {

}
```

I need to print values of other variable, but I need to get actual unsigned int position of this vector loop.

I need to print double vector using this position of this vector.

And how to get the last index of vector.

My problem is for for loop with multiple vectors and getting index from it next to use only last of indexes.

Comment: If you mean indices, you can use [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most effective way to get the index of an iterator of an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator-of-an-stdvector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Angew shows, a simple indexed loop may be preferable when you need indices.

However, it is possible to get the index from an iterator as well:

```
auto a = vect.begin();
auto b = vect2.begin();
auto c = vect3.begin();
for (/*the loop conditions*/) {
    auto index = a - vect.begin();
}
```

It is also possible to get the index of a forward iterator using `std::distance`, but it would be unwise to use it in a loop, since the complexity will be linear for non-random-access iterators.

In the case of forward iterators (and generic code that must support forward iterators), you can write a loop which has both the index variable, and the iterators.

P.S. it is potentially preferable to use pre-increment with iterators. Probably only matters in debug build.

Comment: I'd up if you used `std::distance`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I intentionally don't use `std::distance` here. If the iterators are non-random-accessable, then `std::distance` within the loop increases time complexity of the loop to O(N*N). In a generic code, you should use a separate index variable. But that's not necessary here, as the containers are vectors.

Comment: That is a good line of reasoning. Maybe you should add it to the answer? (Upped regardless).

Comment: Please could you tell me how to get last index of the vector? Thank you.

Comment: @Adam The last index would be the number of elements minus one.

Comment: @user2079303 how i get number of elements? could you please write whole code for getting last index of vector thank you

Comment: @Adam Take look at the page that Angew kindly provided for you.

Comment: ts it max_size?

Comment: @Adam what does the page say about `max_size`?

Comment: Return value
Maximum number of elements.

Comment: So, did you want to get the Maximum number of elements?

Comment: yes but this gives me error if (index == vect.max_size())

Comment: @Adam but earlier you asked how to get number of elements. Number of elements can be different from maximum number of elements.

Comment: Thanks you all for help guys!

Answer (score 4):

It's simple: if you need indices, don't use iterators:

```
for (
  size_t idx = 0, idxEnd = std::min({vect.size(), vect2.size(), vect3.size()});
  idx < idxEnd;
  ++idx
)
{
  auto& obj1 = vect[idx];
  auto& obj2 = vect2[idx];
  auto& obj3 = vect3[idx];
}
```

(The above code initialises `idxEnd` once at the start of the loop, so that it's not needlessly recomputed at each iteration. It's just an optimisation).

Comment: I need to print double vector using this position of this vector. Is it possible by this way? Thank you.

Comment: @Adam `idx` is the index (position) of the currently iterated element in the vectors. I assume that is what you need. If not, please clarify your question to show what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: std::min where its defined?

Comment: Sorry angew but it does not working for me min gives me error, and I dont understand where idxEnd is defined

Comment: @Adam `idxEnd` is defined in the shown snippet. Specifically in the *init-statement condition* part of the `for` expression.

Comment: @Adam You're probably not using C++11, then (which you should be, it's 7 years old now). Or you're missing `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: @Adam Regarding your question "std::min where its defined? " - Google is your friend, and will happily point you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min

Comment: @Adam It seems to me as if you're more or less blindly trying whatever you come upon here, which is not how SO can really be beneficial to you. Perhaps you might want to pick up a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) to get a firmer grasp on C++ basics?