# how to get iterator to a particular position of a vector

Tags: c++, iterator

Suppose i have a

```
std::vector<int> v
//and ...
for(int i =0;i<100;++i) 
 v.push_back(i);
```

now i want an iterator to, let's say 10th element of the vector.

without doing the following approach

```
std::vector<int>::iterator vi;
vi = v.begin();
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
  ++vi;
```

as this will spoil the advantage of having random access iterator for a vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL Vectors: Get iterator from index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671423/c-stl-vectors-get-iterator-from-index)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just add 10 to the iterator. They are intended to "feel" like pointers.

Comment: Don't you want to add 9?
Adding 0 moves to the 1st element,
Adding 1 moves to the 2nd element,
...
Adding n-1 moves to the nth element.

Comment: That's misleading. You're at the first element, which has index 0, so if you add 0, you're not moving and you're still at the first element.

Answer (score 57):

This will work with any random-access iterator, such as one from `vector` or `deque`:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin() + 10;
```

If you want a solution that will work for any type of iterator, use `next`:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator iter = std::next(v.begin(), 10);
```

Or if you're not on a C++11 implementation, `advance`:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin();
std::advance(iter, 10);
```

Comment: thanks... rite now just adding 10 works for me. But i'll take note for the advance.

Comment: I'd prefer std::advance() since it works with any iterator; that way you aren't tied to a specific container.

Comment: @Matt : In all likelihood, if your algorithm requires nth-element access, it would be uselessly inefficient with anything other than random-access iterators anyway; so it would actually be better to use `operator+` instead of `std::advance` and get a compiler error with the wrong iterator type.

Comment: upped for C++11 and generic answer, `next`. hadn't come across that one yet! to add to your distinction of random-access iterators - the  `+` syntax looks nice and will catch any attempts to change to a non-random-access container, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator?rq=1