# Get position of iterator in pointer dictionary of basetype "intrusive doubly linked list"

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

currently I am trying to solve two problems when working with iterators.

`1` When using something like

```
forAllIter(PtrDictionary<phaseModel>, phases_, iter)  
{ 
phaseModel& phase = iter();
.
.
.
}
```

is it possible to get the actual position/index of iterator "iter" (which pointer is the iterator refering to at the moment)?
I know that for the vector class I could use something like described in the following link

[What is the most effective way to get the index of an iterator of an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator)

but unfortunately the class "PtrDictionary" which I have to use does not offer a method "begin()". Furthermore "PtrDictionary" is basically of type "intrusive doubly linked list".

`2`

> **Old Question:**
>
> > If I define a dictionary like
>
> ```
> const dictionary& subDict_Droplets;
> subDict_Droplets = properties.subDict("currentValue");
> ```
>
> Can I create an iterator for the dictionary, set this iterator to a
>   specific position of the dictionary (the position I would get from the
>   first iterator if possible  -> see code snippet 1) and get the content
>   of the dictionary at that position?
>
> I have read the following thread
>
> [how to get iterator to a particular position of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935389/how-to-get-iterator-to-a-particular-position-of-a-vector)
>
> but again class "dictionary" does not have any method "begin()".

**Edit/New**: I have used now a list (which is of "type" vector) like

```
const List<dimensionedScalar> List_Droplets;
List_Droplets = properties.subDict("currentValue");
```

The elements of the vector should be accessable like an array as far as I have read :).

However, the type of the object `phases_` which is of type `PtrDictionary<phaseModel>` (parents: `DictionaryBase< IDLListType, T >` and parent of this: `IDLListType`) which is mentioned in question `1` I can t change.

Any hints, ideas or code solutions are welcome :)

greetings streight

Comment: So doesn't dictionary use some type of container underneath the hood? If not, how was your iterator initialized? It had to "point" somewhere first.  Also, if your dictionary *is* a container, then you need to make it STL compliant by supplying an iterator for it that has begin(), end(), etc. member functions.

Comment: The first code sample is very confusing, and barely looks like C++.  What are `forAllIter`, `PtrDictionary`, `phaseModel`, `phases_`, and `iter`?

Comment: @aschepler : `forAllIter` is a macro, generally a kind of for loop where the iterator `iter` iterates through all elements of `phases_` which is of type `PtrDictionary<phaseModel>` (a pointer dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an iterator corresponds to an index that can easily be found, for example a vector iterator. Here you use distance(vector.begin(), iter);

Sometimes an iterator corresponds to an index that cannot be easily found, for example a list iterator. Here you have to start at begin() and work through, counting as you go. distance() will do this if needed but its obviously a lot slower.

Sometimes the idea of an 'index' does not really apply - I think an unsorted map might be a good example of this. distance will still return a value but it doesn't mean much I think. It might even be implementation dependent - I would have to look that up.