# Iterators and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

Say I have an array in a class and I have to write a member function for that class that places a new value in the middle of the array based on an iterator that is passed in.

For example:

```
void insert(iterator itr, int value)
```

If i was allowed to use integers for indexing then I could just do:

```
array[i] = value;
```

Is there a way to do this same thing with iterators?

Comment: Do you want `insert` to do the equivalent of what the array example does, or what the standard library does?

Comment: what the array example does

Comment: How about `*itr = value;`?

Answer (score 0):

The `insert()` operation for standard c++ container classes implies that the size of the container will be changed, while the indexing operator relies on already available indices, or creates a new one for `std::set` or `std::map` like container classes.

So these operations cannot be compared (made the same) in general.

> If i was allowed to use integers for indexing

An *iterator* is an abstract concept, and the implementation might be more complicated than just transpose it to an integer value used as index for a contiguous array.

Answer (score -1):

You ca just add i to the iterator. They behave just like pointers a clearer esplanation is given on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935389/how-to-get-iterator-to-a-particular-position-of-a-vector)