# Erasing an element from a vector within a for loop - C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to erase an enemies' health value when they are destroyed and I get the error "No instance of overloaded function "..." matches the argument list if I have the following:

```
upgradeHealth.erase(inner)
```

It seems to only accept something like this:

```
upgradeHealth.erase(upgradeHealth.begin())
```

I need the element at position inner to be erased so that it matches the enemy that just got destroyed. Here's the for loop:

```
for (outer = 0; outer < bullets.size(); outer++)              
{
    for (inner = 0; inner < upgrades.size(); inner++)       
    {
        if (upgrades[inner]->HitTest(bullets[outer])) 
        {
            upgradeHealth[inner] -= 1;
            bullets.erase(outer--);
            multiplier += 0.01;
            hasHit = true;
            multiplierTime = 0;
            cout << upgradeHealth[inner] << endl;
            if (upgradeHealth[inner] == 0) 
                upgradeHealth.erase(inner), upgrades.erase(inner), score += 100 * multiplier;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try "upgradeHealth.begin() + inner" instead

Comment: I had considered doing that but glossed over it, however it works so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are only two overloaded member functions `erase` in class `std::vector`

```
iterator erase(iterator position);
iterator erase(iterator first, iterator last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only erase an iterator using the `erase(...)` methods of the `std::vector`.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671423/c-stl-vectors-get-iterator-from-index) for how to get an iterator from an index. Although I would suggest you rethink your algorithm so that you don't need such a conversion.