# C++ STL associative containers: Get iterator from element?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, set

This has been [asked for vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671423/c-stl-vectors-get-iterator-from-index). But is this possible for sets & Co too?

Comment: No, at least not for arbitrary containers. Lookup for iterator traits and concepts.

Comment: What's & co cover? basically no

Comment: Set, multiset, map, multimap. [Check this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Comment: It might be easier to understand this question if you make it clear exactly what you have. E.g. `std::set<string>` and `"banana"`.

Answer (score 1):

set have find function that it returns iterator

```
const_iterator find (const value_type& val) const;
iterator       find (const value_type& val);

eg:
  std::set<int> s;
  std::set<int>::iterator it;

  it = s.find(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c.equal_range(elem);
```

for set-like, or

```
c.equal_range(elem.first);
```

for map-type containers will return a pair of iterators that are equivalent (under the container's rules) to the element.  This takes between O(k) and O(lg n) time, where n is the number of elements in the container, and k is the number of elements pseudo-equivalent to `elem`/`elem.first` (pseudo, as hash collisions modulo bucket count also count).  Average is constant (for unordered)/lg n (for ordered).

Answer (score 0):

Associative containers are pretty much *designed* to find iterators to a given element. So just use the container's `find` function. Note that it's not constant time, it will have time complexity of the container's lookup (logarithmic for ordered containers, average constant for unordered containers):

```
auto iteratorToElement = container.find(element);
```

If you *need* to be able to do this in constant time, you might want to use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) instead, which has this [functionality](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#iterators).